# MogoDB aggregate with $count and $lookup expected performance

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have noticed that counting documents using aggregate with $lookup and $count is somewhat slow (~1.4 seconds for collection with 20k docs running locally), where without $lookup it takes ~14ms.
Regarding indexes: The foreginField of the lookup is `_id` and to be on the safe side I created index on the "localField" as well.
Is such performance "normal"?

MongoDB version 4.2.0 on Windows machine with Node.JS driver.

Here is my test code:

```
var mongo = require('mongodb');

async function start() {
    console.log('Connecting...');
    var client = await mongo.MongoClient.connect('mongodb://test:test@127.0.0.1:27017/test', { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true });
    var db = client.db();

    console.log('Creating data...');
    await db.collection('users').drop();
    var res = await db.collection('users').insertOne({name: 'user', email: 'user@test.com'});

    var projects = Array(20000).fill().map((x, i) => ({ name: `project-${i}`, user: res.insertedId  }));
    await db.collection('projects').drop();
    await db.collection('projects').insertMany(projects);
    await db.collection('projects').createIndex({user: 1}, {name: 'user_1'});

    await runAggregate(db, 'Fetching with $lookup...', [
        {$lookup: {from: 'users', localField: 'user', foreignField: '_id', as: 'user'}},
        {$match: {/* In real I will have here some query involving fields from user */}},
        {$count: 'total'}
    ]);

    await runAggregate(db, 'Fetching without $lookup...', [
        {$match: {/* In real I will have here some query involving fields from user */}},
        {$count: 'total'}
    ]);
}

async function runAggregate(db, msg, agg) {
    console.log('Waiting 2 seconds...');
    await wait(2000)
    console.log(msg);
    var start = Date.now();
    var res = await db.collection('projects').aggregate(agg);

    res = await res.toArray();
    var span = Date.now() - start;
    console.log('Aggregate took: %s msec', span);
}

function wait(ms) {
    return new Promise(res => setTimeout(res, ms));
}

start().then(process.exit);
```

And this is the output:

```
Connecting...
Creating data...
Waiting 2 seconds...
Fetching with $lookup...
Aggregate took: 1429 msec
Waiting 2 seconds...
Fetching without $lookup...
Aggregate took: 14 msec
```

Thanks.

Comment: hi VYW, i'm struggling with same issues, did you come to any conclusion?

Comment: @F.H. Hi, no, didn't find anything and I don't have any "official" support from Mongo so I am kind of stuck... if you find anything please update... Thx

Answer (score 0):

Just in case someone else finds this - what helped me was selecting _id's from the right table and then feeding them to lookup in left table.
Sometimes in batches, it's still times faster than using match + count in aggregate